# Changing src value through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, replace

I have a jQuery variable `merImg` like this

```
var merImg = '<a href="http://xxx.com"><img src="http://om.com/pion/thumbnail/11x65/aa/img.jpg" border="0" align="left" height="11" width="65"></a>';
```

I want to replace `thumbnail/11x65` in the src with `image/40x` using jQuery. Is there a regex to do this easier? Or any logic at all to change it?

Also I want to remove the height and width attribute to the img tag. How do i go about it?

Comment: What is going to happen to that variable? Are you planning to insert it in the DOM?

Comment: either insert it first then edit the attribute or create the html element directly. You cannot write a HTML praser.

Comment: better if you try it with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard [replace()](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php) method of javascript:

```
merImg = merImg.replace('thumbnail/11x65', 'image/40x');
```

as the first argument you can also pass a regExp like this

```
   merImg = merImg.replace(/your regexp/, 'image/40x');
```

To remove height and width in this case you could replace them with an empty string:

```
merImg = merImg.replace('width="65"', '');
merImg = merImg.replace('height="11"', '');
```

I'm no experto of regular experssions but you can write a general regular expression to strip away width and height attributes from a string.

Also a llot of people suggest (correctly) that you should use an HTML parser to parse HTMl. Try to google it if you need more info about it

But in this particulare what i've written should work

Comment: Great and how do i remove the height and width attributes?